# Equation $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k-1}\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(k!)^2(n-k-1)!}=n^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I think  this equality is very inters
prove that:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k-1}\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(k!)^2(n-k-1)!}=n^2$

Answer (score 1):

It helps to rewrite the sum in terms of binomial coefficients as follows:

$$\begin{align} & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-k-1} (n-k) \binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{k} \\ = & (-1)^{n-1} n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k} \binom{n-1}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} \end{align}$$

In *Concrete Mathematics*, p. 170, I see the following identity:

$$\sum_k (-1)^k \binom{\ell-1}{m+k} \binom{s+k}{n} = (-1)^{\ell-1+m} \binom{s-m}{n-\ell+1} $$

Use the values $s=n$, $\ell=n$,and $m=0$:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k} \binom{n-1}{k} \binom{n+k}{n} = (-1)^{n-1} \binom{n}{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1} n $$

So, we just need to prove that identity from CM.